# When browser start implementing JavaScript, how would one start using them while supporting browsers one or two versions older?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

So let's pretend that Chrome and Firefox start supporting `yield` and other JavaScript.next niceties in their X and Y versions respectively.

Are there any recommended strategies (set by W3C, for example) for how to use them while letting our Web apps also run in Chrome X-1 and FF Y-1?

Comment: I guess it really depends on the feature. Some can be easily simulated, like `Objects.keys()`, so it's easy to create a wrapper around them. Other features which change the syntax actually or create new keywords might be more difficult to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use a new feature in HTML, CSS or JS only when all stable versions of most popular browsers support it (these are >90%), but with a notification for the users that do not have them, like "Please upgrade your browser to the last version". Some of the features can be simulated, other - not, so if it's possible, do it, but every time try do the best for the user.